# Specifying foreign key in the mapping file

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping

How in the mapping file can I specify a `foreign key` ? In the following mapping file `id` is the foreign key. How can I specify that ?

```
<hibernate-mapping>

  <class name="org.suhail.pojo.Scheduled" table="scheduled">
      <id name="sid" column="sid" type="integer">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="id" column="id" type="integer" />
      <property name="sdate" column="sdate" type="date"/>
      <property name="stime" column="stime" type="time" />
      <property name="tweet" column="tweet" type="string" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more then one way to specify foreign relationships like one-to-many, many-to-one or many-to-many.

You can go through this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html) to better understand about Associations